# parse a string in localStorage

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, local-storage

I have a string in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("listOfNames","<%= myList.getNames() %>");
```

The string it get's is actually a vector converted into a string

```
"[name1,name2,name3,name4]"
```

I would like to be able to parse it after I put it in localStorage (I want to be able to search for a specific name with an index)

How would I go about doing this? or would I need to even parse it if I could just traverse it?

Comment: How about using JSON ?

Comment: localStorage.listOfNames.slice(1,-1).split(",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listOfNames'))

will turn that string into an array for you. works with objects too.

Comment: no, JSON.parse will only parse JSON, not plain array literals of names.

Comment: I don't want to rely on JSON if I don't have to. The more plugins you use the harder it is map out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

No, I beg to differ on the previous answer, for Objects.

Here is a simple example,

```
var nameObj = {"name":"Mathew"};

localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(nameObj));

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name')); //Will return the object
```

The stringify and parse can be assisted by a utility function to keep it modularised. But, I found it okay in implementing in my project.